# How to use laravel collection's unique method when array key contains period

Tags: laravel, laravel-collection

Laravel collection unique method is now working for array when key consist period

```
$a = [
    ['contact.name' => 'abc'],
    ....
];
```

when I tried to call unique method on `contact.name` it return only one item

Answer (score 0):

Found it

used closure function

```
collect($contacts)->unique(function($contact) {
     return $contact['contact.name'];
})->values()->all();
```